# Mongo/Meteor: Insert data from from other MongoDB Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to embed a document from one collection into another, here a *UoM* into *Products*.

```js
Template.NewProduct.helpers({
  ...
  uoms: function() {
    return UoM.find();
  },
  ...
});

Template.NewProduct.events({
  //Submit and Add to Database
  'submit form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    selectedUoM = UoM.findOne({
      _id: event.target.uomid.value
    });
    var doc = {
      name: event.target.name.value,
      category: event.target.category.value,
      suppliers: selectedSup,
      uomid: event.target.uomid.value,
    };
    Products.insert(doc, function(error, result) {
      ...
    });
  },
});

========= Collections ===========
import SimpleSchema  from 'simpl-schema';

Products = new Mongo.Collection("products");
Products.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Product Name",
    max: 200
  },
  suppliers: {
    type: Array,
    label: "Suppliers",
  },
  'suppliers.$' : {type: String},

  category: {
    type: String,
    label: "Category"
  },
  // Unit: unit , 50kg bag, 25kg bag, 22.5kg barrel etc...
  uomid: { //This one is working with UoM._id
    type: String,
    label: "Unit of Measurement",
  },
  uom_data: { //Need to populate this one with _id, name, unit, unitname from UoM collection
    type: Array,
    optional: true
  },
```

```html
<template name="NewProduct">
  ...
    <label for="uomid">Unit of Measurement</label>
    <select class="sel2js" name="uomid">
      {{#each uoms}}
        {{> uomprod}}
      {{/each}}
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submitNewProduct" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    
  
<template name="uomprod">
  <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}} - {{unit}} {{unitname}}</option>
</template>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".sel2js").select2();
      };
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What kind of help do you need? Does this code work? What error message do you get, and from which place in the code. (It is helpful if you can post this information as well as your code). Please edit your post to add this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple since you've already found the UoM document, your `selectedUoM` variable will contain a simple js object which can be directly assigned to a key in your other collection.

```
selectedUoM = UoM.findOne(event.target.uomid.value);
var doc = {
  name: event.target.name.value,
  category: event.target.category.value,
  suppliers: selectedSup,
  uomid: event.target.uomid.value,
  uomdata: selectedUoM
};
Products.insert(doc,...
```

Note that since `uomid === selectedUoM._id` you have a small redundancy in your model. You can easily eliminate the `uomid` key altogether.

You also need to alter your *Products* schema to support an *object* for `uomdata` instead of an *array*! - you're only inserting a single document, not an array. To avoid having to specify the substructure you also have to use `blackbox: true`.

```
  uom_data: { //Need to populate this one with _id, name, unit, unitname from UoM collection
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
  },
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent a whole day trying to get the answer.